# How to optimize the makespan?

Tags: anylogic

In my problem I want to optimize the makespan of a model where a fixed number parts have to be processed. For each part are two type of machines available one typeA/typeB. A is faster but needs more resources then b. Each part has a parameter "Workflow" that determines on which machine the part is processed (1=Type A and 2=typeB...) How can i code the objective function for an optimization experiment that the runtime/makespan is minimized? 
Thank you in advance for your help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0kek.png)

Comment: You need to have an influencing factor that can be modified. Introduce a double parameter with a probability for your selectOutput. In the AnyLogic Optimization Experiment set this parameter as your variable input parameter. Now you can set for example the output number (root.sink.count()) as your objective function to be maximised.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but is there a way where you can let the model decide parameter value should be set  for each part so that you have in the end a list kind of: Part1=1 Part2=1 Part3=2...Partn=2? So the model decides the sequence for each machine by setting the parameter vaules for each part and not a probability for the "whole" model?

Comment: You mean a sequence optimization. No, that can't be done with standard modules of AnyLogic.

Comment: to optimize a sequence of parts you need artificial intelligence, not optimization